# Customize Newsletter Template?

Tags: magento, customization, newsletter

i am using Magento 1.5.1.0. I Have already changed all transaction E-Mails in my Magento Project. But i have one last Problem. I have not found a way to change the newsletter Template? Is there a way to change the used template like the other transaction E-Mails?

Regards,
Bertie

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Why don't you just create a newsletter template? That fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have 1.7 but i think the menu is the same
If i understand your question, in your admin dashboard you should look under System > Transactional Emails > Add new template. From the options field (labeled Template) choose Newsletter ... (there are three templates), load each of them and change them.
Also for the actual newsletter, from admin dashboard chose Newsletter > Newsletter Templates and add a new email.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But these E-Mails are only the templates for subscribe and unsubscribe E-Mails (in Magento 1.5.1.0). It would be nice to have a newsletter template in  the filesystem (under version control). But i think this is not possible.